# SAS use value from one observation to overwrite different one

Tags: arrays, select, sas, overwrite

I have a data set with two main variables of interest now - Major and Major_Code. These should match up 1 to 1 but there are some errors I need to fix and what I've found is that for 14 Major_Code values, there are two different Majors. This is only due to a change in spelling or punctuation, like "ed." and "education". They are supposed to have the same value here but don't.

So I have a table with 7 pairs. Each pair has the same Major_Code and different a Major. How can I select one of the Major vales to use for each code? My only idea was through an if-then statement but that seems horribly inefficient.

I found the doubled values like this:

**proc freq data=majorslist;
    tables Major_Code/out=majorcodedups;
run;**

**proc print data=majorcodedups;
    where COUNT > 1;
run;**

So I can easily find these observations but can't extract certain values to overwrite onto another observation. I've looked into arrays, macros, sql and transpose but it's all a bit over my head right now.

Logically it would work like this:

from obs i to n, find value for variable x at obs i, output value onto variable y at obs i, go to obs(i+1) and repeat.

Comment: The key is to determine how you want to choose which value for "Major" is correct.  The rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some rule for determining which MAJOR is correct for a MAJOR_CODE, you should do this:

This assumes `majorslist` is a dataset of every major/major_code pair whether unique or not - but only one per major/major_code pair.

```
proc sort data=majorslist;
by major_code major;
run;

data majorslist_unique;
set majorslist;
by major_code major;
if first.major_code and last.major_code then output;
else do;
*rule to determine whether to output it or not;
end;
run;
```

So, you now have the major_code/major relationship.  Let's say you picked `if first.major_code then output;` as your rule (ie, take the major_code with the alphabetically first major value).

Now, you need to apply this to your larger dataset.  There are a lot of ways to do that - merge this on is one, format is another, for starters.  Format works like this:

Create a dataset with `FMTNAME, START, LABEL` defined.  For each value of `MAJOR_CODE`, construct one row like that, where `START` is `MAJOR_CODE` and `LABEL` is `MAJOR`.  We'll also add an extra line that says what to do with non-matches (in case you get new values of major_code).

```
data for_fmt;
set majorslist_unique;
fmtname='MAJORF'; *add a $ if MAJOR_CODE is a character variable;
start=major_code;
label=major;
output;
if _n_=1 then do;
  hlo='o';
  call missing(start);
  label='NONMATCHED';
  output;
end;
keep fmtname start label hlo;
run;

proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;
```

Now you have a format, `MAJORF.` (or `$MAJORF.` if MAJOR_CODE is character), that you can use in a `PUT` statement.

```
data my_bigdata2;
set my_bigdata;
major = put(major_code,MAJORF.);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I almost get the idea. I'm going to just run the code instead of trying to break it down immediately. I don't know if I explained myself clearly that one major_code might be matched to two majors, due to spelling issues, but two major_code values are never matched to one major. The error is definitely one way.

The main trick that I didn't know was by sorting and using the first.id reference, one can output one of the two choices for the pair across all major_codes. It's really powerful to be able to act on internal groups like this after sorting. Thank you again :)